# Parameterized SQL Query Incorrect Syntax

Tags: sql, powershell, prepared-statement

The way I understand parameterized SQL queries is the way to avoid escape character errors. Yet I still encounter this problem.

```
try {
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory

    $abc = Get-ADUser -ResultSetSize 9998 -Properties employeeid,samaccountname,Department,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,mail,useraccountcontrol,telephonenumber,cn,title,mobile,company,description,manager

    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $connection.ConnectionString = "server=server.local;database=db;trusted_connection=true;"
    $connection.Open()

    $command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $command.Connection = $connection

    #$command.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@department",[Data.SQLDBType]::VarChar, 250)))
    #$command.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@physicalDeliveryOfficeName",[Data.SQLDBType]::VarChar, 200)))

    foreach ($user in $abc) {
        $command.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@physicalDeliveryOfficeName",[Data.SQLDBType]::VarChar, 200))).value = $user.physicalDeliveryOfficeName
        $command.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@department",[Data.SQLDBType]::VarChar, 250))).value = $user.Department
        #$command.Parameters['@department'].value = $user.Department
        #$command.Parameters['@physicalDeliveryOfficeName'].value = $user.physicalDeliveryOfficeName

        #if (!$user.department)                 { $Command.Parameters['@department'].value = [System.DBNull]::Value  }
        #if (!$user.physicalDeliveryOfficeName) { $Command.Parameters['@physicalDeliveryOfficeName'].value = [System.DBNull]::Value  }

        $insert = "INSERT INTO [Database].[ad].[UserAccountsT] (employeeid,samaccountname,distinguishedName,givenname,sn,title,department,physicaldeliveryofficename,email,telephoneNumber,mobile,company,description,useraccountcontrol,cn,manager) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}','{12}','{13}','{14}','{15}')" -f $user.employeeid,$user.samaccountname,$user.DistinguishedName,$user.GivenName,$user.Surname,$user.title,$user.Department,$user.physicalDeliveryOfficeName,$user.mail,$user.telephonenumber,$user.mobile,$user.company,$user.description,$user.userAccountControl,$user.cn,$user.manager
        $command.CommandText = $insert
        $command.ExecuteNonQuery() > $null
        $command.Parameters.Clear()
    }
} catch {
    Write-Host Everything goes wrong at $_ for $user at $user.physicalDeliveryOfficeName $user.Department !!!
} finally {
    $connection.Close()
}
```

But when there is a `'` in the name I still get an error:

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near 's'.

`$user.physicalDeliveryOfficeName` value is "Park 's avonds".

Comment: As a side-note: cramming as much as possible into a single statement makes your code much harder to read and debug. I *strongly* recommend you resist the temptation.

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but you are not using parameters correctly. You add the parameters to the command, but then you using format strings to insert string literals into `$insert`. You should be doing something more like `insert into (field) values (@field_param)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using a prepared statement (parameterized query) at all. Using the format operator for inserting strings into a string template is no different from building the statement by concatenation.

Your code should look somewhat like this:

```
$command = New-Object Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$command.Connection = $connection
$command.CommandText = 'INSERT INTO [table] (field1, field2) VALUES (@foo, @bar)'

foreach ($user in $abc) {
    $command.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter('@foo', [Data.SQLDBType]::VarChar, 200))).Value = $user.physicalDeliveryOfficeName
    $command.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter('@bar', [Data.SQLDBType]::VarChar, 250))).Value = $user.Department

    $command.Prepare()
    $command.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
    $command.Parameters.Clear()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer isn't meant to replace Ansgar's but regarding syntax I wanted to share a nice alternative with people who might appreciate it. `using namespace` is used to refer to the types in shorthand.

```
using namespace System.Data
using namespace System.Data.SqlClient

$Command = [SqlCommand]::new()
$Command.Connection = $Connection

# Set values
$Command.Parameters.Add('@foo', [SqlDbType]::VarChar, 200).Value = 'foo'
$Command.Parameters.Add('@bar', [SqlDbType]::VarChar, 200).Value = 'bar'

# Show values
$Command.Parameters | Select-Object -Property ParameterName, Value

# Console Output
#
# > ParameterName Value               
# > ------------- -----               
# > @foo          foo                 
# > @bar          bar
```