# need to convert string "2020-07-05T12:41:52.000Z" into datetime in powershell

Tags: string, powershell, datetime

create a powershell script. but the data in the .csv contains string "2020-07-05T12:41:52.000Z" how do convert the string to datetime for my sql table.

```
$database = 'Database'
$server = '192.168.1.1'
$table = 'KS_Invoicing'
$path = '\\hmks01\c$\temp\'

$CSVs = get-childitem $path -Filter *.csv
foreach ($c in $CSVs){

Import-CSV $path$c | ForEach-Object { 
$_.PSObject.Properties | Foreach-Object {$_.Value = $_.Value.Trim()} 

$column1= $_."Column Date" 

if ($column1) {

$query= "insert into "+$table+" VALUES ('"+$column1+"')"  

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $database -ServerInstance $server -Query $query -U ks  -Password ks2020
}

}
Move-Item $path$c "\\hmks01\c$\temp\Archive"
}
```

Comment: Use [parametrized statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45737286/503046) instead of catenating strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date string you show can be directly cast to a datetime object.

```
[datetime]"2020-07-05T12:41:52.000Z"

Sunday, July 5, 2020 7:41:52 AM
```