# Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated."

Tags: powershell

while i passed the value from splunk by running this script and inserted into database, i got below error :

**Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated."**

could you help to suggest how to fix that issue?
passing date time value from splunk is
`$jsonObj.result.F10="2.312" $jsonObj.result.F11="3.212" $jsonObj.result.F15="6.412" $jsonObj.result.datetime = "2021-12-29 19:00:00"` and in database table date time column value also same format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"

below is my code:

```
param ($jsonContent)

$jsonObj = $jsonContent | ConvertFrom-Json

write-host $jsonObj.result.F10
write-host $jsonObj.result.F11
write-host $jsonObj.result.F15
write-host $jsonObj.result.datetime

$serverName = "FSMSSTEST132,3067"
$databaseName = "ITReport"
$tableName = "dbo.SPK_ITMetricsChart"
$YourUserID = "MES123";
$YourPassword="Asd123";

$hostName = "$jsonObj.result.F10","$jsonObj.result.F11" ,"$jsonObj.result.F15"
$value1 = "Delivery"
$time = $jsonObj.result.datetime
$site = "F10N","F11","F15"

$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$serverName';database='$databaseName';User ID= '$YourUserID'; Password= '$YourPassword'"
$Connection.Open()
$Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$Command.Connection = $Connection
for($i=0;$i -lt $hostName.Length; $i++)

  {
    $insertquery="
  INSERT INTO $tableName
      ([Datetime],[Value],[Category],[Site])
    VALUES
      ('$time','$($hostName[$i])','$value1','$($site[$i])')"
  $Command.CommandText = $insertquery
  $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
   
  
  }

$Connection.Close();
```

Comment: I guess your `$jsonObj.result.datetime` is a string type (`$jsonObj.result.datetime.gettype()`) and your database field is actually a `[DateTime]` type. Try: `$Time = Get-Date($jsonObj.result.datetime)`

Comment: Use `write-host $insertquery` and double-check that the insert query contains what it should. That being said, it is a best practice to use [parametrized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45737286/503046) instead. No more worries about escaping, and no door open to SQL injection.

Comment: @iRon i still get same error "Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated." after i change my date time code to 
$time = Get-Date($jsonObj.result.datetime)